# jQuery post from ajax loaded div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Can't seem to figure this one out. I have a page where contents of one div is loaded via ajax. That same div has forms in it and after submit it should refresh to show new content. But without reloading the whole page. How is that possible? I am so lost right now.

Also I don't think it's the best style to loop new form for every row but can't think of anything else now. If someone could help me would be awesome.

display.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
$("#list").load("list.php");
});
</script>
 .................
 other stuff
 .................

  <div id="list"></div>
```

list.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".add" ).click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({type:"POST", url:"ajax_post.php",
 data:$("#"+id).serialize(), cache:false, timeout:10000 });

  location.reload();

   }); });
  </script>

 .................
 other stuff
 .................
  <?php
   foreach($list as $l): ?>
  <form id="<?php echo $l->id;?>">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $l->pd;?>" name="pd">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $l->sf;?>" name="sf">
  <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $l->status;?>" class="add">
   </form>
   <?php
   endforeach; ?>
```

ajax_post.php is just insert query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your requirements. But way don't you try changing your script code with something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".add" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {type:"POST", url:"ajax_post.php",
      data: $("#"+id).serialize(), cache:false, timeout:10000 
      success: function() {
        $("#list").empty()
        $("#list").load("list.php");
      }});
});});
</script>
```

The intention is to clean the #list element and refill it once the ajax call succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for answering but this it not working for me. This script is in different file than #list div so should that empty() and load() even work in that kind of scenario?

Comment: Damn, I'm sorry. I got it sort of working with this. Div loads like it should. But I have a new problem :D When this is not ajax and I post it directly from display.php everything goes to database like it should. But now every value is 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, this is weird. It works perfectly with Safari but Firefox. Firefox reloads page but doesn't submit anything to database. Could there be something with that JS that Firefox can't understand?

Comment: try `console.log(data)` and find out what did you send to the server.

Comment: Console in firebug says: (an empty string). Chrome and Safari both insert data correctly.

Comment: The form does not specify where to send the info when non-jaxa submitted. It will send the info to the current URL (display.php or list.php). While the ajax call always send the data to ajax_post.php

Comment: Also the form does not specify a method, HTML's default is GET, while your ajax call uses POST. Be sure your PHP code handles both in the same way

Comment: Yep. No luck.. Console says only empty string now too.. :(

Comment: you lost me there. please try to keep the questions as concrete as possible, remember we only see a really small picture of your project. That JS should work fine both in Safari and Firefox, problem should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

First, put your form in a separate php file so that we can call it using AJAX, e.g forms.php.

When the page loads, you call `list.php` using `$.load()`

```
$('#list').load('list.php')
```

From my understanding, the list will contain forms, and when the form is submitted, you want the form to reload again without having page refresh. So this is my approach.

```
$('#list').on('submit', '#formIDfromPHP', function(){
    var data = $(this).serializeArray()
    $.post('ajax_post.php', data, function(result,status){
        console.log(result)
    })
    // Dynamically load it again without refresh.
    $('#list').load('list.php')

    // Or maybe you want to load the form only, hence the external forms.php
    // $('#list').load('form.php')

    // Prevents default form submission behaviour.
    return false;
})
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but this is not working for me. Yes, I want to refresh that #list div contents after form submit. That last one $l->status is basically V or X. V=active, X=not. I think this is the right idea but just can't seem to get it working :(

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with status?

Comment: It's a submit button but also it says if user has that book. V=yes, X=no. If clicked V it changes to X and clicked X it changes to V